# thenAnswer method is not being invoked even though the arguments for the actual query and the mocked query match

Tags: flutter, mockito

I have a tests file that tests the `addToCart` method, which indirectly calls the `computeVoucher` method. The `computeVoucher` method makes an API call to the GraphQL client, which is mocked for testing purposes. The arguments for the actual query and mocked query match, but the `thenAnswer` method is not invoked. The mocks are generated using Mockito.

Here is the code:

test.dart

```
test('When only voucher is added and exceeds cart total', () async {
  final Cart cart = Cart();
  cart.voucher = Voucher('test12345', true, 'Flat', 250, 1, 250,
      client: mockClient, id: '12345');

  await cart.addToCart(product);
  expect(cart.pricingSummary.totalAmount, 0.0);
});
```

voucher.dart

```
Future<int?> computeVoucher(
  String? voucherId, List cartProducts) async {
  Map<String, dynamic> variables = {
    'voucherId': voucherXid,
    'cartProducts': CartProduct.getProducts(false, cartProducts),
    'cartLineItems': CartProduct.getProducts(true, cartProducts)
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> result = await (client!
      .query(query: computeVoucherQuery, variables: variables));
  return result['computeVoucherDiscount'].toInt();
}
```

voucher_mock.dart

```
Future query(
  {required String query, var variables, bool networkOnly = true}) async {
  when(_client.query(QueryOptions(
          document: gql(computeVoucher['query']),
          variables: computeVoucherVariables,
          fetchPolicy: FetchPolicy.networkOnly)))
      .thenAnswer((realInvocation) async =>
          MockQueryResult(data: computeVoucher['response']));
}
```

The error message is: "Error: Null is not a type of Future".

Comment: I thought this might be a problem with the [default `equals` matcher behavior](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#argument-matchers) in Dart's mockito because the QueryOptions instances are separate, but graphql-flutter already supports deep equality via `==` in [QueryOptions](https://github.com/zino-hofmann/graphql-flutter/blob/7ada44dcc2aba54a3961f823177b2b01962d3e99/packages/graphql/lib/src/core/_base_options.dart#L103), so it probably isn't causing your problem.

Comment: We're not using [graphql-flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter), we're using [graphql](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql)

Comment: They refer to [the same GitHub repo](https://github.com/zino-hofmann/graphql-flutter/tree/main/packages/graphql); try clicking on the GitHub Repo link on [the graphql page you linked](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql). The QueryOptions dart source I linked is from the graphql package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a Future or Stream from a method stub, [use thenAnswer](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito#a-quick-word-on-async-stubbing).

> **Using `thenReturn` to return a `Future` or `Stream` will throw an `ArgumentError`.** This is because it can lead to unexpected behaviors.
>
> ...
>
> Instead, use `thenAnswer` to stub methods that return a `Future` or `Stream`.

You can try using `thenReturn` instead as expected cannot be a Future or Stream, due to Zone considerations.